# Blazor: Using a keyboard event together with DebounceInterval in a MudBlazor textfield

Tags: binding, blazor, textfield, keyboard-events, mudblazor

I am using MudBlazor to develop a client-side Blazor-WASM app. I have a search field which is to update the bound variable in real-time (i.e. not only after losing focus, but while typing). Furthermore, I want to **clear the [MudTextField](https://mudblazor.com/api/textfield#pages)'s text if user presses the -key** (so they don't have to use the clear-button if they don't want to). Well, if I do it like this, it works perfectly:

```cs
<MudTextField Label="search something" Variant="Variant.Text" Clearable="true"
    @bind-Value="SearchText" Immediate="true"
    @onkeydown="e =>  KeyboardEventHandler(e)"
/>

@code {
    public string SearchText { get; set; }

    private void KeyboardEventHandler(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Code == "Escape") { SearchText = string.Empty; }
    }
}
```

This works like a charm. However, I need the component to **wait a little while before updating the variable**, because each change triggers a new filtering process that may block the UI for a bit (since BlazorWASM, at the time, doesn't support multithreading). So, I use `DebounceInterval`, i. e. do it like this:

```cs
<MudTextField Label="search something" Variant="Variant.Text" Clearable="true"
    @bind-Value="SearchText" Immediate="true" DebounceInterval="350"
    @onkeydown="e =>  KeyboardEventHandler(e)"
/>

@code {
    public string SearchText { get; set; }

    private void KeyboardEventHandler(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Code == "Escape") { SearchText = string.Empty; }
    }
}
```

If I do it like this, when typing faster than the debounce interval, **only the last typed character is kept** (i.e. every character typed replaces the one before it), as long as the @onkeydown event is used, too.

How can I make this work? I'd be grateful for a possible solution or ideas towards it.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to implement a debouncer.  The simplest is just to do a backoff of say 300ms before doing your lookup. This gives you a 300ms + your lookup period.

Here's a slightly different method that uses Tasks and waits either the backoff period or the query period whichever is the longer.

The deboucer with lots of comment code to explain what's happening.

```cs
public sealed class ActionLimiter
{
    private int _backOffPeriod = 0;
    private Func<Task> _taskToRun;
    private Task _activeTask = Task.CompletedTask;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool>? _queuedTaskCompletionSource;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool>? _activeTaskCompletionSource;

    private async Task RunQueueAsync()
    {
        // if we have a completed task then null it
        if (_activeTaskCompletionSource is not null && _activeTaskCompletionSource.Task.IsCompleted)
            _activeTaskCompletionSource = null;

        // if we have a running task then everything is already in motion and there's nothing to do
        if (_activeTaskCompletionSource is not null)
            return;

        // run the loop while we have a queued request.
        while (_queuedTaskCompletionSource is not null)
        {
            // assign the queued task reference to the running task  
            _activeTaskCompletionSource = _queuedTaskCompletionSource;
            // And release the reference
            _queuedTaskCompletionSource = null;

            // start backoff task
            var backoffTask = Task.Delay(_backOffPeriod);

            // start main task
            var mainTask = _taskToRun.Invoke();

            // await both ensures we run the backoff period or greater
            await Task.WhenAll( new Task[] { mainTask, backoffTask } );

            // Set the running task completion as complete
            _activeTaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(true);

            // and release our reference to the running task completion
            // The originator will still hold a reference and can act on it's completion
            _activeTaskCompletionSource = null;


            // back to the top to check if another task has been queued
        }

        return;
    }

    public Task<bool> QueueAsync()
    {
        var oldCompletionTask = _queuedTaskCompletionSource;

        // Create a new completion task
        var newCompletionTask = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        // get the actual task before we assign it to the queue
        var task = newCompletionTask.Task;

        // replace _queuedTaskCompletionSource
        _queuedTaskCompletionSource = newCompletionTask;

        // check if we already have a queued queued task.
        // If so set it as completed, false = not run 
        if (oldCompletionTask is not null && !oldCompletionTask.Task.IsCompleted)
            oldCompletionTask?.TrySetResult(false);

        // if we don't have a running task or the task is complete , then there's no process running the queue
        // So we need to call it and assign it to `runningTask`
        if (_activeTask is null || _activeTask.IsCompleted)
            _activeTask = this.RunQueueAsync();

        // return the reference to the task we queued
        return task;
    }

    private ActionLimiter(Func<Task> toRun, int backOffPeriod)
    {
        _backOffPeriod = backOffPeriod;
        _taskToRun = toRun;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Static method to create a new deBouncer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="toRun">method to run to update the component</param>
    /// <param name="backOffPeriod">Back off period in millisecs</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ActionLimiter Create(Func<Task> toRun, int backOffPeriod)
            => new ActionLimiter(toRun, backOffPeriod > 300 ? backOffPeriod : 300);
}
```

And a demo page to show how to use it:

```cs
@page "/"
@using Blazr.UI

<h3>Test</h3>

<input class="form-control mb-2" type="text" @oninput=OnInput />

<div class="alert alert-info">
    @message
</div>
@code {
    private ActionLimiter _limiter;
    private string? message;
    private string? value;

    public Test()
        => _limiter = ActionLimiter.Create(this.RunTask, 300);

    private async Task OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        value = e.Value?.ToString() ?? null;
        await _limiter.QueueAsync();
    }

    private async Task RunTask()
    {
        // simulate doing your search
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        message = value;
    }
}
```

There's a full CodeProject article here describing this technique and how to build a Typeahead control using it.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5351256/Building-a-Blazor-Autocomplete-Control

Comment: The component I am using already has a debounce functionality built-in, which works in principle. As I've described, there's only a problem once I use my own @onkeydown handler. So, I'm not sure if the solution lies in re-inventing my own debouncer - that being said, thanks for the code example and your effort - maybe it'll lead to my solution eventually.

Comment: You can get the MudBlazor source which you can probably modify if you want.

Comment: Hm, while I'm not sure if I am skilled enough to do this successfully at this point, it sure is an intriguing thought to try to find the source of the problem myself that way. I guess I'll do some digging once I have enough time  - the sources [are on GitHub](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor), after all.